# Can't scale socket.io locally most likely because of the session store

Tags: session, node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I have a master process that forks workers that are socket.io servers all that using the cluster module and of course socket.io.

The problem is that unless I specifically say that I want only one worker, my code just doesn't work. I wrote it before the cluster module existed and it worked fine as a single process, and it seems it's the same now.

What happens when it forks 4 workers (number of cpu cores) with the RedisStore as the session store is the following:

```
node_redis: no callback to send error: Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
Caught exception: Error: Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
```

And if I use the default MemoryStore, on the socket.io logs it keeps repeating

```
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 3883988821204831830
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 12039436321106971132
   debug - xhr-polling received data packet �43�5:::{"name":"estimatepp","args":[70821530]}�20�5:::{"name":"ready"}
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/217474157959916242?t=1328357263590
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 7:::1+0
   debug - set close timeout for client 217474157959916242
   warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect
   info  - transport end
```

And on the client side (browser) logs it yields a weird error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'open' of object #<c> is not a function
handshake.c.sessionidsocket.io.js:2
d.ready
```

The error on the client side doesn't happen with RedisStore, and none of the errors happen with only one worker. I have strong evidence to believe that the `wrong number of arguments for 'hset'` error is in the RedisStore code of socket.io because I don't use any hset at all in my code, and again it doesn't happen with MemoryStore...

What do you think it's happening ? Is this worth reporting to the socket.io guys ?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue... Though I don't get any errors in the client-side and particularly on Android devices - both webview and native browser. In my case I'm using UTF-8 encoding in the transmitted data. The thing I found is the moment I emit any Cyrillic text/data, the message is sent properly, however, immediately after that, the transport is discarded:

```
   debug - set close timeout for client 8983972932106614064
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 8983972932106614064
   debug - xhr-polling received data packet �88�5:::...
```

I believe it is very likely a problem of the REDIS store.

BTW, may be if you notice the xhr-polling received data packet, the redis store (I believe) sends another request, named "ready"... Same here... I have two requests after the blocking one and same issue...

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/816 - this is the problem solution...